# Ways to run an OS for a watch using a Raspberry Pi/Arduino

Tags: linux, operating-systems

I am thinking of making a smartwatch using a Raspberry Pi/Arduino (Zero W if I use a Raspberry Pi). 
Is it possible to put an OS such as Tizen on it so that I can turn it into a smartwatch? (Anything OS which works with IOS is fine)
If not how can I make a custom Linux OS which would allow me to program it in such a way that this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [not such a great idea](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1447788). Historically, there was once a Linux distro called 'Pebble', and they had (one of) the very first "smart watches" that IIRC, was built on their OS. I think Pebble has been "reincarnated", but here's an issue: pi=ARM, pebble=X86 (different architecture). Not impossible of course, but a big project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to run Tizen on raspberry. It's a propritary OS.

You can create a linux image for Raspberry with something like [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/). It's a tool which create image with a linux kernel and an initramfs. But its not easy to create/personalise and you will need some good known about programming.

Comment: Could I put Asteroid OS on it?

Comment: Yes, it could be possible. But you will need to make a port for it.It will not be easy. Asteroid OS is based on OpenEmbedded which is based on an linux OS. So in theory you can.
https://asteroidos.org/wiki/openembedded/